# Control of a D.C. motor reversing contactor

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I've got a forklift with a partially functional motor controller. As I've got a bit of experience with electronic engineering (as opposed to electrical), I have a few questions that I was hoping to get some help with.

The current setup looks like this:

[image: Current Setup]

The original controller is very hard to get hold of. A close alternative with very similar specs is available. However, it doesn't have the "FWD Input" or "REV Input". For the original controller, the internal block diagram is as follows:

[image: Internals]

The new controller is as follows:

[image: New controller]

The contactors that the "FORWARD" and "REVERSE" control are [Albright DC182](http://www.albrightinternational.com/products/dc182/).

I guess, my question is, what might the "F/R Contactor Driver" (in the block diagram) do? Because as far as I can tell, the contactors works by connecting completing the circuit across the coils.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's going to be the part the outputs the current to actuate the contactor.

Comment: That's what I assumed, however, how does the second controller actuate the contactor? I'm struggling to see on the DC182 what current is required to operate the contactor.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet somewhere? The info given on the site is pretty unhelpful.

Comment: The last page of this document is the best I've managed to get my hands on: http://www.albrightinternational.com/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/SW180-Catalogue-Rev-No-4-June-2011-Electronic-Issue.pdf

Comment: What models are the old and new controller?

Comment: Both made by Curtis. Old: 1205x-5301. New: 1204M-6301

Answer (score 1):

The F/R contactor driver doesn't seem to have any function in normal operation, but what it does do is drop out the feed to the contactors in the event of a coil short - "Forward, reverse, and bypass contactor driver outputs are internally protected
against shorts in the contactor coils" from http://assets.curtisinstruments.com/Uploads/DataSheets/1204x05manual.pdf

On the new arrangement such a short would only be dealt with by the control fuse blowing. This results in a loss of drive, on the old arrangement, there's the possibility of braking to a halt using the reversing contactor if the forward contactor fails.